# Parse Json in VB.NET into listview

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing, listview

I'm developing a costum launcher for Minecraft, with more functions. I have a problem with parsing this json file:https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/versions.json (I'm using Newtonsoft.json to parse), I want to parse, and display result in listview (like this: http://pbrd.co/1ueP2Su) , but I don't know what code can do this.
Sory for my bad English, Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a new structure that might look like this:

```
Public Structure Version
    Public ID As String
    Public TIME As String
    Public releaseTime As String
    Public type As String
End Structure
```

And then, maybe on a button click, write this

```
    Dim allVersions = New List(Of Version)
    Using wc = New WebClient() With {.Proxy = Nothing}
        Dim JSON = Await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/versions.json") 'Downloads the JSON file
        Dim values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(JSON) 'Converts it to JObject

        For Each i In values("versions").Children() 'Gets the versions
            YOUR_LISTBOX.Items.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).ID)
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: Thanks, it works good, and can u tell me how to add subitems (type) too?

Comment: Well assuming you're using a **ListView**, you could do something like this: `YOUR_LISTVIEW.Items.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).ID).SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).type)`

Comment: Thanks man a lot! 
But i have one last question how to select auto the item in listview by text? Thank, even so, you have helped a lot.

Comment: I think about: versionmanager.listview1.items(versionname).selected = true, but it not works.

Comment: Set the **HideSelection** property of the listview to false and then add this code to your program, it will select version 1.8: `YOUR_LISTVIEW.Select()` `YOUR_LISTVIEW.Items(5).Selected = True`